# Delete duplicate mails Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, outlook, duplicates

Im trying to create a VBA macro that checks if there is a duplicate mail (looks at subject) and then deletes the mail.

This code works but is deleting the oldest duplicates. It's counting in descending order and I can't seem to get the sorting of the items to work.

Basically I need help figuring out how to make sure the "newest" duplicate by received time gets deleted.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim oFolder As Folder
    Dim oEmail As MailItem, oItems As ItemProperties, oItem As ItemProperty
    Dim cMail As Collection
    Dim i As Long
    Set oFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set cMail = New Collection

    With oFolder
        ' .Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
        If olMailItem <> .DefaultItemType Then Exit Sub
        For i = .Items.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set oItems = .Items(i).ItemProperties
            Debug.Print oItems("ReceivedTime")

            If Not oItems("ReceivedTime") Is Nothing Then
                Set oItem = oItems("ReceivedTime")

                '// Week old
                If oItem >= Date - 7 Then
                    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
                    '// Delete Duplicate Subject
                    cMail.Add oItems("Subject"), oItems("Subject")
                    On Error GoTo 0
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, oItems("Subject"), oItems("ReceivedTime")
    oFolder.Items(i).Delete

    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @DmitryStreblechenko's answer:

The following will keep the `MailItem` with the oldest date and delete more recent ones with the same subject.

For convenience `TargetFolder` and `MinDate` are configurable but optional. They default to the currently visible folder and seven days ago.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates(Optional TargetFolder As Folder, Optional MinDate As Date)
    Dim Items As Items, Email As MailItem
    Dim i As Long, Dupes As Object

    If MinDate = vbEmpty Then MinDate = Date - 7
    If TargetFolder Is Nothing Then Set TargetFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

    Set Dupes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set Items = TargetFolder.Items
    Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"

    Debug.Print "Dedupe <" & TargetFolder.FolderPath & ">, " & Items.Count & " items"

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is MailItem Then
            Set Email = Items(i)
            If Email.ReceivedTime >= MinDate Then
                If Dupes.Exists(Email.Subject) Then
                    Debug.Print "DELETE: " & Email.Subject
                    'Item.Delete
                Else
                    Dupes.Add Email.Subject, 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This makes use of a `Scripting.Dictionary` because unlike the `Collection` object it supports a handy `Exists()` method.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm! Scripting.Dictionary will be handy for some other macros :)

Comment: I had this almost ready when he posted his answer and I did not want to throw it away. Note the `TypeOf` check and the explicit type cast from `Items(i)` (which is `Object`) to `MailItem`, which enables IntelliSense for the `EMail` variable in the VBA IDE. You could also do `Objects(i).Subject`, but then you would not get auto-completion.

Comment: When using it for a mailscript Sub RemoveDuplicates( Email As Outlook.MailItem) it doesn't include the received e-mail that triggers the script. Suppose I have to create a separete eventhandler

Comment: Yes, I suppose so, too.

Answer (score 4):

Cache the Items collection before entering the loop (otherwise you get a brand new Items COM object each time), sort it on ReceivedTime (Items.Sort), then loop from Count down to 1.